# How do I append values in order to an existing list using only cons?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, cons

In lisp I am trying to append values in order to a list using only the basic functions: setq cons car and cdr.

I can create the list backwards but I am having difficulty figuring out how to push them in order, how can this be done?

```
(setq list NIL)
(setq list (cons 1 list))
(setq list (cons 2 list))
(setq list (cons 3 list))

Result:
(3 2 1)
```

Comment: What exactly would you consider a solution?  Obviously you could do (setq list (cons 3 list)), then (setq list (cons 2 list)), etc., but I doubt that's what you want.  Are you asking how to insert a value at the end?  I don't think that you'll be able to do that when your only mutating form is setq, because you'll need to modify the **cdr** of a **cons**, and for that you'll need **setf** or **rplacd**;  **setq** only works with variables (or, for the pedants, variables and names bound with symbol-macrolet).

Comment: Somewhat of a bad question.  Obviously can't be done in those terms, which is why `setf (cdr ...)` exist as a special form. Since ancient dialects of List this was aliased to `rplacd` although few use that alias https://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node150.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lisp lists are *singly* linked lists.  Really, there's no "list" as such, just a bunch of cons-cells, also called pairs, that we interpret as a list by convention.  **(cons x y)** produces a pair **(x . y)**. As a special case, when the cdr of a cons is a list, e.g., in **(x . (1 2 3))** we write the pair as **(x 1 2 3)**.  And the symbol **nil** is the empty list, so **(x . nil)** is **(x)**.  So, with cons, all you can do is create a new pair.  If you have an existing list, **l** = **(a b c…)**, and a new element, **e**, you could create the list **(e a b c…)**, which you've already done, or you can create the new list **((a b c…) e)**, which isn't really what you want.

To modify the *tail* of the list, you need to be able to update the cdr of an existing cons cell.  E.g., if you have **(a b c)**, which, in the non shorthand form, is **(a . (b . (c . nil)))**, you could do:

```
(setf (cdr (cdr (cdr the-list))) (list 'd))
```

and you'd *replace* the **nil** with **(d)**, to get **(a b c d)**.  That requires using **setf**, rather than **setq**, since **setq** can only modify variables, not arbitrary *places* (like the cdr of a cons cell).

Idiomatically, if you're getting items in the reverse order that you need them, it's a common idiom to create the list in reverse, just like you're doing (or using push, etc.), and then to *reverse* it at the end.  E.g., here's what a one-list version of mapcar could look like:

```
(defun mapkar (function list)
  "A simple variant of MAPCAR that only takes one LIST argument."
  ;; On each iteration, pop an element off of LIST, call FUNCTION with
  ;; it, and PUSH the result onto the RESULTS list.  Then,
  ;; destructively reverse the RESULTS list (it's OK to destructively
  ;; modify it, since the structure was created here), and return it.
  (let ((results '()))
    (dolist (x list (nreverse results))
      (push (funcall function x) results)))
```

Here's a tail recursive version of the same thing:

```
(defun mapkar (function list &optional (result '()))
  (if (endp list)
      (nreverse result)
      (mapkar function
              (rest list)
              (cons (funcall function (first list))
                    result))))
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an surprising broad topic. First of, normally, you don't append single items to a list. The usual way of handling situations like the one you're probably in is by first collecting the wanted values into a list, and then reversing that list to get the order right:

```
(let ((my-list '()))
  (dotimes (i 10)
    (setf my-list (cons i my-list)))
  (nreverse my-list)) ; NOTE: nreverse destructively modifies its argument
;;=> (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
```

Of course you can write yourself an function to "append" a value to a list, returning a new one:

```
(defun my-append (value list)
  (if (null list)
      (cons value '()) ; or use (list value)
      (cons (first list) (my-append value (rest list)))))
```

You can transform this to a tail recursive variant, but that won't solve the main issue of this function: It needs to traverse the whole list for each element to append it. Thus, this is in `O(n)` with `n` being the length of the list.

Another issue is that this function is *consing* a lot, that is it is generating a lot of additional *cons cells*, causing a lot of work for the memory management. One could solve that by making it destructively modifying its argument, though.

See also the function [`append`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_append.htm#append) that is already part of Common Lisp.

To give you an overview, you can either

- collect the values in the "wrong" order (using `cons`) and then destructively reverse that list ([`nreverse`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_revers.htm))
- collect the values in the "wrong" order and then create a new, reversed list with the values in the right order ([`reverse`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_revers.htm))
- actually `append` your values to the list, tolerating possible quadratic or worse run time.
- actually append your values to the list, destructively modifying the lists structure ([`nconc`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_nconc.htm)). This is an improvement against `append` because you don't need to allocate lots of new cons cells, but you still have the run time issue.

---

Based on [uselpa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1193075/uselpa)'s "hack" I wrote functions to operate with such a "list". It consists of a cons, whose `car` points to the beginning of the list (i.e. the list), and whose `cdr` points to the last cons cell of the list. Though that last cell is always `(nil . nil)`, simplifying appending a value:

First, one sets the `car` of that last cell to the new value, then sets the `cdr` to a new cell `(nil . nil)`, and finally returns that new "list":

```
(defun empty-al ()
  (let ((cell (cons nil nil)))
    (cons cell cell)))
(defun cons-al (value al)
  (cons (cons value (car al))
        (cdr al)))
(defun append-al (value al)
  (let ((new-cell (cons nil nil)))
    (setf (cadr al) value
          (cddr al) new-cell)
    (cons (car al) new-cell)))
```

Comment: But OP said that he allowed to use just "etq cons car and cdr", doesn't look like a possible taslk for my, with just these functions.

Comment: `first` == `car` and `rest` == `cdr`, which makes the `my-append` satisfy this requirement.

Comment: Yes, but what about `if` and `null`?

Comment: Well, I could "unroll" this, but where's the point? `setq`, `cons`, `car` and `cdr` as **only** basis are in no way turing complete. Thus one could only write the reversed list by hand, which leaves writing the list as just `'(1 2 3)` as better alternative.

Comment: oh ok so its not possible then, I was really stumped for a few hours thinking it was. I was trying to create a lisp interpreter and had only the very basic functions.

Answer (score 2):

There's a technique (I don't remember if it has a specific name) which consists in creating an initial cons cell with any `car` value and keeping a pointer to the `cdr`. Appending then consists of `setf`ing the pointer's `cdr` and advancing the pointer. The list you want will at any time be the `cdr` of the initial cons cell:

```
? (progn (setq lst (cons 'head nil)) (setq lst-p lst) (cdr lst))
NIL
? (progn (setf (cdr lst-p) (cons 1 nil)) (setq lst-p (cdr lst-p)) (cdr lst))
(1)
? (progn (setf (cdr lst-p) (cons 2 nil)) (setq lst-p (cdr lst-p)) (cdr lst))
(1 2)
? (progn (setf (cdr lst-p) (cons 3 nil)) (setq lst-p (cdr lst-p)) (cdr lst))
(1 2 3)
```

So this only uses `setq`, `cons`, `cdr` but also `setf`.

Answer (score 0):

The usual idioms are either to use the `:collect` feature of an extended `loop` or to accumulate by pushing (as you described) and reverse in the end.

As an example, here are two versions of a simple `range` function that returns the integers from 0 below n:

```
(defun range (n)
  (loop :for i :below n
        :collect i))

(defun range (n)
  (let ((list ()))
    (dotimes (i n)
      (push i list))
    (reverse list)))
```

Under the restrictions you mentioned, I'd recommend implementing your own `reverse` and using it.  Here is a tail recursive example, but note that tail recursion needs not be supported by your Lisp implementation.

```
(defun own-reverse (list &optional (acc ()))
  (if (endp list)
      acc
      (own-reverse (rest list)
                   (cons (first list) acc))))
```